# tf::transformPoint cannot find frame

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am trying to convert PointStamped values from the narrow_stereo_link frame to the base_link frame using tf::TransformListener::transformPoint. However, I keep getting:

*terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf::LookupException'*

*what():  Frame id / does not exist!*

In my code I have the following function call,

mTransformListener.waitForTransform("/narrow_stereo_link", "/base_link", ros::Time::now(), ros::Duration(5.0));
mTransformListener.transformPoint("/base_link", min_in, min_res);

On executing

*rosrun tf tf_echo narrow_stereo_link base_link*

on the terminal, I get the following output :

At time 1340824941.479

- Translation: [0.152, -0.117, -1.386]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.110, 0.061, 0.869, -0.479]

  ```
        in RPY [0.214, 0.133, -2.119]
  ```

which means that the two are connected in the tf_tree, which is also seen in the frames.pdf generated by

rosrun tf view_frames

Can anyone help me with this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37412/tf::transformpoint-cannot-find-frame/) by [Mayank](https://answers.ros.org/users/2162/mayank/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-06-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your call to `waitForTransform`, don't use `ros::Time::now()` but your point's time stamp and don't hard-code the frame id but use your point's frame id. Don't forget to check for the return value to be true. If the 5 seconds timeout pass without the transform becoming valid, `waitForTransform` will return and the following call to `transformPoint` will throw an exception.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mayank](https://answers.ros.org/users/2162/mayank/) on 2012-06-28**:
Thanks for your answer. I edited the code following your advice, but it still doesn't seem to work. I've posted the details below.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My first guess would be that the input point "`min_in`" does not have a frame_id set. You have to make sure that the input point is in its correct frame by specifying its `header.frame_id`. It looks to me like this field is blank in your code.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mayank](https://answers.ros.org/users/2162/mayank/) on 2012-06-27**:
Thanks for your answer. I can't post a long comment, so please read my question posted below!